# C++ cli assembly attributes missing

Tags: c++-cli, assemblyinfo

Hi I created as sample C++ CLI project in VS.
By default it has many assembly attributes like company, product etc.
On Windows7 or Vista, when I right click on the assembly and go to the Details tab, the assembly is missing some of the attributes that I added.

Any Idea why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

Which attributes are missing? The Windows Explorer properties dialog only supports a subset of the .NET assembly version attributes.

Comment: Some of the attributes missing are, AssemblyDescriptionAttribute,
AssemblyConfigurationAttribute,
AssemblyCompanyAttribute,
AssemblyProductAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 file system is different from Windows XP (I don't know about Vista). In particular, under Windows XP, you could append Summary information to any file (Title/Subject/Author/Category/Keywords/Comments), but not under Windows 7. If you copy such a file to Windows 7, this information is just thrown away. Many users have complained about this.

Comment: But if I create some assembly with C#.NET, I can view all the attributes in Windows 7.